# Adding to Join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, join

I'm pretty new to Rails and trying to learn. I have a User table an Event table and a UserEvent join table. When a User creates an Event they are added to the join table. However, I want other Users than the event-creator to be able to click on a "join event" button and add him or her self to the UserEvent join table so that I can tell how many people are attending an Event. How do I go about setting this up? Would I need to create a UserEvent Controller? I am thoroughly confused on how to approach this other than knowing to use a counter_cache once the functionality allows for it.

Resources are as follows:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :activities
  end
  resources :activities, only: [:index, :show]

  resources :users do
    resources :events
  end
```

Comment: You can just do it in the Event controller.  When creating an event with a user associated to it a record will be added automatically to the join table.  Just make sure the relationships are defined correctly in the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<<` ActiveRecord method (which [I found out about here](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/activerecord-association-extensions/)) to do add to associations

Here's what you could do:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :events do 
    member do
       post :join
    end
end

#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
end

def join
   @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
   @event.users << params[:user_id] #might need more than just params[:user_id]

   redirect_to root_path
end

#app/models/event.rb
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_events
    has_many :users, through: :user_events
end

#app/views/events/show.html.erb
#will need to pass user_id somehow (use form)
<%= link_to "Join", event_join_path(@event), method: :post, data: {confirm: "Really Join?"} %>
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying to click on the "Join" button. Any thoughts? "No route matches [GET] "/users/1/events/26/join" "

Comment: Change `link_to` to `button_to`. This will generate a POST action rather than GET.

Comment: lol sorry, I should have put method: :post in the link! Ammended answer

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Programming and rails are still so new to me that taking those considerations into account doesn't yet come naturally however now I have no excuse going forward! It is now working so many thanks to you Rich and thanks to Robin as well.

Comment: No problem!! Always good to see someone learning something great! Remember to add as much as you can to the Rails community too :)